# Positioning a button and preventing movement?

Tags: css, button, positioning

As you can see from this image of my site:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/33735427334/in/dateposted-public/

My button is crammed right underneath the randomly generated text. Instead, I'd like to lower it.
But additionally, I'm trying to keep it completely "anchored" to the page, because right now when I click the button, a random image generates, but that image is moving the button vertically depending on the size of the image. Not good.

Instead, I'd like that button to remain in the same position, always.

Any thoughts/help would be appreciated. I'm still quite new to all this. Thank you. -Wilson

link to the actual website  http://www.wilsonschlamme.com/test4.html

css:
*It's pretty simple. First two elements here are controlling centering the page. The rest are self explanatory, showtext refers to the random text generator.

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

body{
text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
}

button {
color: #900;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 150%;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

h1{
margin-top:20px;
font-size: 250%;
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
font-family: hobeaux-rococeaux-sherman, sans-serif;



}

img {
max-width:600px;
max-height:440px;
box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px grey;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 1px;
margin-top:20px;
}

#ShowText{

overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
word-wrap: break-word;
padding-top: 100px;
max-width: 1000px;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: vendetta, serif;
line-height: 25px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#buttonfun {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Wrap the `img` with a div:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
   <img src="images/297.jpg" />
</div>
```

and add the CSS:

```
.image-wrapper {
  height: 440px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Chris for all your help. I actually solved it as we were going back and forth here at the end. I simply used this instead of the bottom elelemnt:    top: 900px;}    That did the trick, stays in one place, doesn't resize horizontally or vertically. I am however going to try out your new solution as well, I want to take extensive notes on this so I don't run into this issue again. Thanks so much for your help, you're awesome man!